# How to use the cProfile mod when the python file takes arguments?

Tags: python, command-line, cprofile

I'm trying to run the cProfile mod on a python program I have. The program has flags and it's currently saying "no such file or directory" when I try to add the flags into the argument.

I've tried running

```
python -m cProfile -o resultFile "myFile.py"
```

This returns "Too few arguments"

I also tried:

```
python -m cProfile -o resultFile "myFile.py --flag1 val"
```

And I got, "No such file or directory"

I'd like for this to run with the flags given from the command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to pass the full command as a single argument. Just like you run your script normally:

```
python myFile.py --flag1 val
```

You can add to that the cProfile options:

```
python -m cProfile -o resultFile myFile.py --flag1 val
```